# Django overwrite parts in inherited templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I have set up the following templates

**base.html**

```
{% extends 'base/main_base.html' %}

{% block main-content %}
    <h1>Header stuff<h1>
    ...
    {% block article-content %}
    {% endblock %}

{% endblock %}
```

**article.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block article-content %}
   <h2>Content</h2>
   <p>More content</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Now, I connected a view to the article.html, and I want use the dynamic view data to overwrite the 'header stuff'  in the 'base.html' template. Problem is, the view is connected to the article.html, which inherits from the base.

Is there a way to override parts of the base template from the child template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create another [template block](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance) in your **base.html**

```
{% extends 'base/main_base.html' %}

{% block main-content %}
    <h1>{% block header %}Header stuff{% endblock %}<h1>
    ...
    {% block article-content %}
    {% endblock %}

{% endblock %}
```

and overwrite the block in your **article.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block header %}My overwritten headline{% endblock %}

{% block article-content %}
   <h2>Content</h2>
   <p>More content</p>
   ...
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also check, in base.html, if a "header" value is injected to the template from the article (or any other view):

**base.html**

```
{% extends 'base/main_base.html' %}

{% block main-content %}
    <h1>
        {% if header %}
            {{ header }}
        {% else %}
            Header stuff
        {% endif %}
    <h1>
    ...
    {% block article-content %}
    {% endblock %}

{% endblock %}
```